# proving that the subspace topology and the metric topology are the same

Tags: general-topology

My problem states:

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $Y$ be a subset of $X$. Consider the function $d_Y:Y\times Y \to \mathbb{R}$, given by $d_Y(x,y)=d(x,y)$.

(a) Prove that $d_Y$ is a metric on $Y$.

(b) Prove that the topology induced by $d_Y$ on $Y$ is the subspace topology that $Y$ inherits from the metric topology on $X$.

I have finished part (a), and for part (b), I have the following:

(b) To prove that the topology induced by $d_Y$ on $Y$ ($\mathcal{T}_{d_{_Y}}$) is the subspace topology that $Y$ inherits from the metric topology on $X$ ($\mathcal{T}_Y$), we will show that $\mathcal{T}_Y = \mathcal{T}_{d_{_Y}}$.

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $Y$ be a subset of $X$ with a metric $d_Y:Y\times Y \to \mathbb{R}$, given by $d_Y(x,y)=d(x,y)$, $\mathcal{T}_Y$ be the subspace topology that $Y$ inherits from $X$, $\mathcal{T}_{d_{_Y}}$ be the topology that on $Y$ induced by $d_Y$, and $\mathcal{T}_{d_{_X}}$ be the topology on $X$ induced by $d$. To prove, that $\mathcal{T}_Y = \mathcal{T}_{d_{_Y}}$, we must show that (i) the basis elements in $\mathcal{T}_Y$ are open sets in $ \mathcal{T}_{d_{_Y}}$, and that (ii) the basis elements for $\mathcal{T}_{d_{_Y}}$ are open in $\mathcal{T}_Y $.

(ii) Let $ {B}_{d_{_Y}}(x,\epsilon) \in \mathcal {B}_{d_{_Y}}$; then $ {B}_{d_{_Y}} (x, \epsilon) = \{y \in Y: d_Y(x,y) < \epsilon \}$. Since $Y \subset X$ and $x,y \in Y$, it follows that $x,y \in X$; also note that $d_Y(x,y) = d(x,y) < \epsilon$. So we have that ${B}_{d_{_Y}} (x, \epsilon)  \in \mathcal{B}_{d_{_X}}  = \{ {B}_{d_{_X}} (x, \epsilon) :x \in X, \epsilon>0\}$. But we also know that ${B}_{d_{_Y}} (x, \epsilon) \subset Y$, and therefore ${B}_{d_{_Y}} (x, \epsilon) \cap Y = {B}_{d_{_Y}} (x, \epsilon)$. Hence, as ${B}_{d_{_Y}} (x, \epsilon) \in \mathcal{B}_{d_{_X}}$ and ${B}_{d_{_Y}} (x, \epsilon) =   {B}_{d_{_Y}} (x, \epsilon) \cap Y$, it must be the case that ${B}_{d_{_Y}} (x, \epsilon)\in \mathcal{B}_Y = \{{B}_{d_{_X}} \cap Y: {B}_{d_{{_X}}} \in \mathcal{B}_{d_{_X}} \}$, which by theorem 3.5 is the basis for $\mathcal{T}_Y$. Thus, $\mathcal {B}_{d_{_Y}} \subset \mathcal {B}_Y$, which means that basis elements for $\mathcal{T}_{d_{_Y}}$ are open in $\mathcal{T}_Y $, i.e.  $\mathcal{T}_{d_{_Y}} \subset \mathcal{T}_Y $.

However, for the other direction (i), I am a bit unsure about. Unfortunately, I am not allowed to add a picture in here; I was trying to post the picture of the sets and the basis. But basically, what I have in there is the set X, inside of which I have the set Y, I have a bubble blown in $X$, $B_{d_X}(x,\epsilon)$, so that it intersects with $Y$ and $x \notin Y$. I am trying to show that basis element $B_Y = B_{d_X}(x,\epsilon) \cap Y$ is an open set in $\mathcal{T}_{d_Y}$, since it can be presented as a union of basis elements for $\mathcal{T}_{d_Y}$, i.e. union of those $B_{d_Y} (x', \delta)= \{ y' \in Y: d_Y(x',y')<\delta \}$. And since for every point $x'$ in $B_{d_X}(x,\epsilon)$ there is a $\delta>0$, such that $B_{d_X}(x',\delta) \in B_{d_X}(x,\epsilon)$, this must be possible to do, I just need to make sure that the $\delta$ bubbles are fully contained in $Y$, which is also fine, since $\delta \in \mathbb{R}^+$, and between every 2 reals there is another real; however, I am worried about the points that are in the intersection of the boundary of $Y$ and the bubble $B_{d_X}(x,\epsilon)$. How can I blow open bubbles for them that will be inside $Y$? The bubbles will have to either intersect $X$ or not quite reach $Y$'s boundary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $T$ and $T'$ are topologies on a set $Y$, then to prove $T=T'$ it suffices to find a base (basis) $B$ for $T$ and a base $B'$ for $T'$ such that

(i) whenever $p\in b'\in B'$ there exists $b\in B$ with $p\in b\subset b',$ and

(ii) whenever $p\in b\in B$ there exists $b\in B'$ with $p\in b'\subset b.$

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $Y\subset X.$ Let $T$ be the subspace topology on $Y$ as a subspace of $X$ and let $T'$ be the topology on $Y$ induced by the metric $d.$

Let $C$ be the set of all open $d$-balls of $X.$ Let $B=\{Y\cap c:c\in C\}.$ Now $C$ is a  base for the topology on $X$ so $B$ is a base for $T.$

Let $B'$ be the set of open $d$-balls of Y. Then $B'$ is a base for $T'$.

(i'). If $b'\in B'$ then for some  $y\in Y$ and some real $r>0$ we have  $$b'=\{z\in Y: d(y,z)<r\}=Y\cap \{z\in X:d(y,z)<r\}\in B$$ by def'n of $B.$

So $B'\subset B$. So (i) is satisfied by $b=b'.$

(ii'). If  $p\in b\in B $ there exists $x\in X$ and real $r>0$ such that $p\in b= Y\cap \{z\in X:d(x,z)\}=Y\cap B^X_d(x,r). $  Now $B^X_d(x,r)$ is open in $X$ so there exists real $s>0$ such that $B_d^X(p,s)\subset B_d^X(x,r).$

So let $b'=Y\cap B_d^X(p,s)\in B'$ and (ii) is satisfied .

Remark. In (ii') we can let $s=r-d(x,p).$ The triangle inequality then implies $B_d^X(p,s)\subset B_d^X(x,r).$ This is also used to show beforehand that  $C$ is in fact a base for a topology on $X.$

Comment: Example: Let $X=\Bbb R$ and $d(x,y)=|x-y|.$ Let $Y=[0,2]\cup [4,6]$ and let $B$ be the set of bounded open intervals. Then $(1,5)\cap Y\in B \setminus B'.$

Comment: There is a period and a space missing in (ii') but when I try to edit them in they are present  in the raw text and in the answer and re-typing it doesn't change it.

Answer (score 1):

Let $U =B_{d_X}(x;\epsilon) \cap Y \in \mathcal{T}_Y.$ Then $$U = \{y \in X \cap Y \mid d_x(x,y) < \epsilon \} = \{y \in Y \mid d_y(x,y) < \epsilon \} \in \mathcal{T}_{d_Y} $$Thus,  $\mathcal{T}_Y \subseteq \mathcal{T}_{d_Y}$. Note that reading this proof backwards gives a proof of (i),

Comment: This was something I wrote in one of my first attempts, but I thought that I cannot use the distance function $d_Y$, since I need to assume that I am working with a different topology than the metric one, which means that I might be assuming what I need to prove by using the $d_Y$ function.

Comment: Not too sure if this answers your question, but in the two sets the functions $d_X$ and $d_Y$ can be interchanged in the two sets since they are still the same set, which can be easily proved by showing they are a subset of one another if one wants to go into that much detail.

Comment: I think I am struggling to understand something else now. Let me explain it this way. Let's imagine that the given distance functions are both Euclidean distance functions. Then our basis elements induced by the function $d_Y$ on $Y$ must be open circles that are contained in $Y$, i.e., the boundary of $Y$ (let us suppose now that $Y$ is closed in $X$) will not be contained in any of them, thus, it cannot be contained in their union. However, a part of Y's boundary is contained in $B_{d_X}(x,\epsilon) \cap Y=B_Y$. So this basis elem. $\neq$ union of $B_{d_Y}$s, no?